# How can I force axios to send empty array?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm sending an array of integers with axios from a vue.js application, method PATCH.

If there are values, to data is passed as expected.

But if there are none (e.g. all items removed from the multiselect), then the payload is empty. I need it to be sent so the items can be removed from the database, a pretty normal use case.

My update method is as follows:

```
 update({ commit, dispatch }, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const params = {};
      params[data.name] = data.value;
      console.log(params)
      axios({ url: '/api/' + module + '/' + data.id, params, method: 'PATCH' })
        .then(response => {
          //Replace the full object in the store with the one we get back from the patch operation
          commit('update', response.data.data);
          dispatch('postUpdate', data)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err)
        })
    })
```

My *console.log* confirms that the params array is the way I expect

```
Object { data_items: [] }
```

But the network request shows that it's being removed and nothing posted.

I can also confirm that when I make a select any values, the request works as expected and sends to the server to be persisted.

For example

*Request for populated selection*
http:///api/processes/16?data_items[]=2

*Request for emptied selection - no query paramaters*
http://example.com/api/processes/16

How can I force axios to send the empty array?

Comment: Any specific reason your wrapping the array in an object, you could just sent the array by itself. By default Axios wouldn’t be removing the values, if your payload is what you say it is, Axios will be sending it. Can you provide an example of the request sent?

Comment: No particular reason for using an object, I probably did it without thinking. I've swapped it for an array and get the same outcome. I've added URL's to the post to illustrate what happens when the select is emptied.

Comment: I have to say I’m confused as to why “data_items” is a query param. The data should be apart of the request body. Can you provide a fiddle of this for us to reproduce?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm sending a form serialized into an object, and if one of the values is an empty array axios strips it from the request, for some reason.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am currently saving an object which has a key with an array value. However, this array can be empty sometimes as the user cannot select an option.

So, when I am sending this object with this key with an empty array, the place that receive the request is getting null instead of empty array [].

Answer (score 1):

Using [querystring](https://github.com/Gozala/querystring)'s stringify as serializer and adding an empty string to the empty list works for me.

e.g.

```
const queryObject = {myList: myList.length > 0 ? myList : ['']}


return axios.get(url, {params: queryObject, paramsSerializer: querystring.stringify}).then(...)
```

Then the url becomes http://example.com?myList= which my backend interprets as receiving an empty list for myList query param.

Comment: Thanks! This works but it is converting an empty array to an array of one empty item and `querystring` will happily stringify it.

Wish there could a `skipEmptyArray: true/false` property similar to [skipNull and skipEmptyString](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#skipnull)